# Java application server behind IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: java, iis, glassfish, windows-server-2008

NB: I have just posted the same question on `ServerFault`, [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/392898/java-application-server-behind-iis-7-5-on-windows-server-2008). If this is not the right place, please let me know so that I'll remove the question from here.

I have a Java application server (GlassFish, indeed, but the problem is the same for any other application server, I guess), running on port 8080. And I have IIS 7.5 listening on port 80 as by default configuration.

I want to avoid people typing the port because it's unprofessional. So I want that when somebody types

```
http://myserver
```

the traffic is directed to IIS. And this is how it already works now. But I also want that when somebody types

```
http://myserver/java
```

the traffic is directed to port 8080 and consequently my GlassFish splash screen is displayed. If I have deployed an application on GlassFish under context root `app1`, typing

```
http://myserver/java/app1
```

should access the application.

How can I do this? I have tried with adding some rules with the `URL Rewrite` utility from IIS7.5 UI, but this shows the port after the rule has rewritten the url, and I want to avoid it.

Comment: Also note that your generated links in the glassserver instance will point to your internal URL's unless you explicitly reconfigure them.

Comment: This question does belong to ServerFault, as you should configure IIS to forward Java traffic. Probably you should check out, http://tomcatiis.riaforge.org/ Glassfish is based on Tomcat and this should work fine with IIS.